# CSS flip-animation not working in Safari 9.0

Tags: html, css, sass, safari, flip

Ok, i got an answer, i added `backface-visibility: hidden;` to front and back of the card, and forgot to add it to the rotating part, in my case it was "flip-item-inner". Hope it help someone :)
__

Actyally flip is working, animation showing, and I can even see the backside of the card, but when animation is end, instead of backside, there is white background. Tried to add class istead of :hover, result is the same, it flips and then white background instead of backside. Im using SASS with autoprefixer so all the prefixes should be at their places. It works fine in chrome and mozilla, on android devices, but fails on iOS, in safari and even chrome: 
Tested on browser stack: os_version=9.0 device=iPhone+6S

https://codepen.io/ndeviant/pen/Owjera

```
                                <div class="flip-item slideritems-item">
                                <div class="flip-item-inner">
                                    <div class="flip-item-front">
                                        <div class="flip-item-img-box">
                                            <img src="http://www.spinsouthwest.com/content/000/images/000249/257025_54_news_hub_209660_656x500.jpg" alt="">
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="flip-item-info">
                                            <div class="flip-item-meta">
                                                <time class="flip-item-meta-item flip-item-date" datetime="2017-10-30 14:27:18">30 октября 2017</time>
                                                <a href="" class="flip-item-meta-text flip-item-meta-item">Лайфхаки</a>
                                            </div>                                              
                                            <div class="flip-item-title">
                                                Блок при наведении 
                                                курсора на него
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="flip-item-back">
                                        <div class="flip-item-info">
                                            <div class="flip-item-meta">
                                                <time class="flip-item-date flip-item-meta-item" datetime="2017-10-30 14:27:18">30 октября 2017</time>
                                                <a href="" class="flip-item-meta-text flip-item-meta-item">Лайфхаки</a>
                                            </div>
                                            <a href="" class="flip-item-title">
                                                Блок при наведении 
                                                курсора на него
                                            </a>
                                            <a href="" class="more-arrow">
                                                <span>Показать все</span>
                                            </a>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
```

---

```
.flip-item
position: relative
max-width: 265px
text-align: left
perspective: 1000px
font-family: sans-serif

// Flip 
&:hover
    .flip-item-inner
        transform: rotateY(180deg)
        box-shadow: 0 0 25px 0 rgba(50, 50, 50, .2)

    .flip-item-front
        // opacity: 0

    .flip-item-back
        // opacity: 1

&-inner
    width: 100%
    height: 100%
    transform-style: preserve-3d
    background-color: #fff
    transition: all .35s ease-in-out

&-front
    min-height: 305px
    backface-visibility: hidden
    // opacity: 1
    transition: all .35s ease-in-out

&-back
    position: absolute
    top: 0
    left: 0
    width: 100%
    height: 100%
    backface-visibility: hidden
    background-color: #3E61F9
    color: #fff
    transform: rotateY(180deg)
    // opacity: 0
    transition: all .35s ease-in-out
// End flip

&-img-box
    height: 180px

    img
        object-fit: cover
        height: 100%
        width: 100%

&-info
    padding-top: 12px
    padding-bottom: 20px
    padding-left: 15px
    padding-right: 15px
    font-size: .875rem

&-meta
    width: 100%
    margin-bottom: 15px
    display: flex
    flex-wrap: wrap

    &-item
        color: #9E9E9E

    &-text
        margin-left: auto

&-title
    display: block
    text-transform: uppercase
    text-decoration: none
    font-weight: bold
    line-height: 1.4
    color: #323232

// Backface of the card
&-back
    .flip-item-info
        display: flex
        flex-direction: column
        height: 100%
        padding-bottom: 12px

    .flip-item-meta
        &-item
            color: #fff

    a
        color: #fff

    .more-arrow
        margin-top: auto
```

Comment: You don't have hover state on mobile devices.

Comment: @Observer But it works well on android devices, but on iOS it fail's even in chrome.